# Add Subview at (0,0) adds it at (0,0) point of Safe Area instead of superView

Tags: ios, uiview

In my app I add view via code with simple

```
let imageFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: imageHeaderHeight)
imageHeader = ArtistImageHeaderView(frame: imageFrame)
imageHeader?.imageView.image = viewModel.primaryImage
view.addSubview(imageHeader!)
```

On `iOS 10` it works as expected, **imageHeader** is added at (0,0) point of super view, but on `iOS 11.0` and higher it is added below navigation bar
How can I keep iOS 10's behaviour on newer versions?

Comment: There's some magic in UIKit that can automatically handle UIScrollView insets so that they take the safe area into account. Is there a scroll view (or a subclass thereof) in your view hierarchy maybe? If so, see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior

Comment: Yes, there is tableView set to fill entire screen, it has contentInset set so the imageHeader I placed on top of table's content